# Consuming a secure web service from WCF using supplied wsdl

Tags: wcf, web-services, wsdl, wcf-security, soap-client

I have been given a wsdl and xsd file from a company partner to access their https service.
I have installed the client certificate and can access their API using SoapUI after configuring the security in soapUI.

what are the next steps to consume the API in a .net application?

I have generated the proxy using svcutil.
I have added the certificate to the local machine and current user - trusted root certification authorities
The cert is from the service provider and works through soapUI. its not self signed.

When i make the call to the service i get Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'WEB_SERVICE_URL:11851'.

Do i need to configure https in the config file or what am i missing?

thank you

Comment: If it's not already, your URL should be "https:/ /WEB_SERVICE_URL:11851 ... plus, you should have a class/method following your Port, something like:

https:/ /WEB_SERVICE_URL:11851/WebServiceName/Method

While the xsd will help you craft the xml you'll send, you should get a bit of sample data from this company and try that out.

Comment: It turned out i had to specify the certificate in code

Answer (score 0):

It turned out i had to specify the certificate in code

```
       // Create the binding.

        BasicHttpBinding customerBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        customerBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        customerBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
           HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        // Create the endpoint address. Note that the machine name 
        // must match the subject or DNS field of the X.509 certificate
        // used to authenticate the service. 
        EndpointAddress customerEa = new               
          EndpointAddress("https:URL_OF_SERVICE:11851/WebServices/GetCustomerDetailsService");

        // Create the client.             
        customerClient = new GetCustomerDetails1Client(customerBinding, customerEa);

        // The client must specify a certificate trusted by the server.
           customerClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
            StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
            StoreName.My,
            X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
            "CERTIFICATE_NAME");
```